# Update data fusion table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Is it possible to bulk update data in Google fusion Table. I have more than 1000 rows, I need to update some (I search for something like **Find and Replace** or **Update**). I struggle with **Authorization**.

Comment: Do you want to update Google data or programatically import that data into your system (update existing, insert new)? The former would not be possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry; I found the answer. Got to set the table Public.

Comment: i am trying to update the records of my table using api key but when i am executing the query it is saying login required.